# What does '<?=^' operator do in PHP?

Tags: php

I know `<?=` operator is a short form for `echo` but I don't know what is the `<?=^` operator.

Comment: show an example with  <?=^

Comment: it does not seem to be an operator in PHP. From where you have found it?

Comment: In a Kohana application:

<?=^HTML::nl2br($ratingValue->getValue())?>

Comment: I would say it's a bug in the code. And the most probably version of this line should be interpreted as `<?= ^HTML::nl2br($ratingValue->getValue()) ?>` So as you can see there is no `<?=^` operator. But still I have no idea why someone used `xor` operator with one parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP it will do nothing. In most PHP versions this will produce a syntax error, versions prior to 5.4 will output the tag. [Demo here](http://3v4l.org/5sVmP).

It's likely either a typo or is used in some kind of templating system (I'm not familiar with Kohana).